# Como es la forma correcta de obtener el id de otra coleccion?

Tags: mongodb, go

Estoy realizando una practica de una empresa de venta y fabricacion de videojuegos la cual por el medio donde almaceno la informacion es por mongodb, en la aplicacion un usuario puede tener multiples roles que son solo asignados por el administrador, pero me estoy encontrando con un problema y es obtener el id de los roles para almecenarlos en la coleccion user, pues lo unico que se me ocurrio es tener un slice de string para almacenar los nombres de los roles y por medio de una consulta buscar los id de esos nombres y almacenarlos, pero esta forma creo que no es correcta pues no estoy almacenando un object id si no un string.
Estos son mi estructura rol y usuario:

```
type Role struct {
    ID        primitive.ObjectID `bson:"_id,omitempty" json:"id"`
    Name      string             `bson:"name,omitempty"`
    State     bool               `bson:"state,omitempty"`
    CreatedAt time.Time          `bson:"created_at,omitempty" json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time          `bson:"updated_at,omitempty" json:"updated_at"`
}
type User struct {
    ID        primitive.ObjectID `bson:"_id,omitempty" json:"id"`
    FirstName string             `bson:"first_name,omitempty" json:"first_name"`
    LastName  string             `bson:"last_name,omitempty" json:"last_name"`
    Email     string             `bson:"email,omitempty" json:"email"`
    Password  string             `bson:"Password,omitempty" json:"Password"`
    Avatar    string             `bson:"avatar,omitempty" json:"avatar"`
    Role      []string           `bson:"role,omitempty" json:"role"`
    CreatedAt time.Time          `bson:"created_at,omitempty" json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time          `bson:"updated_at,omitempty" json:"updated_at"`
}
```

Esta es mi funcion de crear usuario:

```
func CreateUser(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 5*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    collection := storage.Connection().Database("testing")
    collectionRole := collection.Collection("roles")
    collectionUser := collection.Collection("users")

    u := &model.User{}
    if err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(u); err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "format incorrect", http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }

    var rl []model.Role
    var roles []string

    cursor, err := collectionRole.Find(ctx, bson.D{{"name", bson.D{{"$in", u.Role}}}})
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "collection not found ", 404)
        return
    }

    if err := cursor.All(ctx, &rl); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
        return
    }

    for _, rol := range rl {
        roles = append(roles, rol.ID.Hex())
    }

    result, err := collectionUser.InsertOne(ctx, bson.D{
        {"first_name", u.FirstName},
        {"role", roles},
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
        return
    }

    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(result)
}
```